# Video upload with Tweetinvi

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

I am using TweetInvi to post video on Twitter.

```
TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials(token.Token,token.TokenSecret,ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsumerKey"], ConfigurationManager. AppSettings["ConsumerSecret"]);

var filePath = string.Format("{0}content\\participant\\video\\{1}.{2}", Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, p.video, "mp4");
byte[] file1 =System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

var tweet =  Tweetinvi.Tweet.CreateTweet(message);
tweet.AddMedia(file1, "video");            
var success = tweet.Publish();
```

Tweet is posting successfully. But video file is missing.
I have used code from  [tweetinvi twwet with media](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Tweets#publish-a-tweet-with-media)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i used tinytwitter https://github.com/SnapStreamJason/TinyTwitter. video uplaod is working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter is using a new upload mechanism for videos. Tweetinvi has not yet released this feature but it will be available in Tweetinvi 0.9.8.2 that I will release today that will contains this specific feature.

In the meantime please follow the instructions available in this [link](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/discussions/640413) (read the mark as answered solution).

---

Update :

You can now use the VideoUploader using Tweetinvi 0.9.8.2. Unfortunately, nuget has some issues so you will have to specify the version for now:

*Install-Package TweetinviAPI -Version 0.9.8.2*

Here is a code sample :

```
var binary = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\video.mp4");
var media = VideoUploader.UploadVideo(binary);
var tweet = Tweet.CreateTweet("hello" + Guid.NewGuid());
tweet.AddMedia(media);
var success = tweet.Publish();
```

Cheers,
Linvi